# My PyQt application not works with error - This application failed to start because no Qt platform

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, pyinstaller

I developed a Python program using `PyQt5` in Windows 10, and it works very well. Then i made it into `.exe` file with `pyinstaller`, but it failed and gave me an error.

```
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized.
Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: minimal, offscreen, webgl, windows.
```

I searched for similar problems in here and google, but i couldn't find the same problem - running `.py` works well but `.exe` failed.

Followings are what i have tried:

- Placing `platforms` folder in the same directory with `.exe` file.
- Setting environment variable `QT_QPA_PLATFORM_PLUGIN_PATH`. (it was already set.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, try the latest version of Pyinstaller because it has some new fixes for PyQt5.
Second try to install latest version of pyqt5 with `pip install -U pyqt5`.
Last but not least, **don't use** UPX with `PyQt5` because it can't properly compress all DLLs.

So you can simply freeze your application without any problem just run:
`pyinstaller -F --noupx <script_name>.py`.

If you still have problem replace the files in `bin` and `plugins` directories in 
`C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\pyinstaller\bincache00_py37_64bit\pyqt5\qt`

from

`C:\Program Files\Python37\Lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt`

and run `pyinstaller <script_name>.spec`

Comment: Thanks! i will try your solution in today.